# Deploying a container from Google Container Registry to a Compute Engine VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry

I am trying to [deploy a container on a Google VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers?hl=fr&_ga=2.263634056.-589845272.1512418739).
From the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers?hl=fr&_ga=2.263634056.-589845272.1512418739) it seems straightforward: specify your image in the container text field and start the VM.

My image is stored in the Google Container Registry in the same project as the VM. However, the VM starts but does not pull and run the docker image. I ssh'ed the VM and `docker images ls` returns an empty list.

Pulling the image doesn't work.

```
~ $ docker pull gcr.io/project/image
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: repository gcr.io/project/image not found: does not exist or no pull access
```

I know we're supposed to use `gcloud docker` but `gcloud` isn't installed on the VM (which is dedicated to containers) so I supposed it's something else.

Also, the VM service account has read access to storage. Any idea?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?  Seems a bit ridiculous that you can't just follow the basic steps to get an existing image in GCR in the same project as the VM to work, given that that's the whole *point* of the 'deploy a container on the VM'.

Answer (score 3):

From the [GCR docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication), you can use [docker-credential-gcr](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/docker-credential-gcr/releases) to automatically authenticate with credentials from your GCE instance metadata.

To do that manually (assuming you have `curl` and `jq` installed):

```
TOKEN=$(curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" | jq -r ".access_token")
docker login -u oauth2accesstoken -p "$TOKEN" https://gcr.io
```

Answer (score 1):

To pull the image from the gcr.io container registry you can use the gcloud sdk, like this:

```
$ gcloud docker -- pull gcr.io/yrmv-191108/autoscaler
```

Or you can use the docker binary directly as you did. This command has the same effect as the previous gcloud one:

```
$ docker pull gcr.io/yrmv-191108/autoscaler
```

Basically you problem is that you are not specifying either the project you are working nor the image you are trying to pull, unless (very unlikely) your project ID is *project* and the image you want to pull is named *image*.

You can get a list of the images you have uploaded to your current project with:

```
$ gcloud container images list
```

Which, for me, gets:

```
NAME
gcr.io/yrmv-191108/autoscaler
gcr.io/yrmv-191108/kali
Only listing images in gcr.io/yrmv-191108. Use --repository to list images in other repositories.
```

If, for some reason you don't have permissions to install the Gcloud SDK (very advisable for working with Google Cloud) you can see your uploaded images on the Google Cloud GUI by navigating to *"Container registry -> images"*